# Is there a way to make the following algo more efficient?

Tags: r, if-statement

Given the following algorithm that returns a value from a predefined enumeration if a random input value `u` is less than some predefined probability in a (cumulative) `prob` vector

```r
val <- 1:5
prob <- c(1/3,1/30,2/15,7/30,4/15)
u <- runif(1)
if (u<prob[1]) 
  { 
    x=val[1]
  } else if(u<prob[1]+prob[2])
  {
    x=val[2]
  } else if(u<prob[1]+prob[2]+prob[3])
  {
    x=val[3]
  } else if (u<prob[1]+prob[2]+prob[3]+prob[4])
  {
    x=val[4]
  } else
      x=val[5]
  }
```

Is there a way to make all this more efficient? I can't figure it out how to do it differently.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative would be to use `findInterval`. For example

```
val <- 1:5
prob <- c(1/3,1/30,2/15,7/30,4/15)
u <- runif(1)
val[findInterval(u, cumsum(c(0, prob)))]
```

This will also work for any number of values

```
u <- runif(1000)
val[findInterval(u, cumsum(c(0, prob)))]
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know whether this is specifically a question about an *algorithm* or whether you want to solve the problem faster.

`sample(val, size = 1, prob = prob)` would certainly be faster than your solution, but I don't know whether the internal algorithm is *fundamentally* any better (e.g. in terms of operation count) than yours.

Looking at the [C source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d1f8ef492464fd68320be9581bde4b09eadc03d6/src/main/random.c#L312-L338) you can see that the algorithm is like yours, except that it computes the cumulative probabilities up-front to avoid repeated addition (and permutes the elements into descending order — I think that's for numerical stability rather than efficiency).

(this is for sampling with replacement; the [without-replacement code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d1f8ef492464fd68320be9581bde4b09eadc03d6/src/main/random.c#L406-L437) looks very similar, except that the machinery for removing previously sampled values makes it a little more complicated)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cumsum` and `which`:

```r
set.seed(3)
u <- runif(1)
#[1] 0.702374

val[which(u < cumsum(prob))[1]]
#[1] 4
```